# Sitefinity, default Lucene relevance of fields

Tags: lucene, relevance, sitefinity-6.x

I have to work with Sitefinity, and I'm trying to determine the default relevance boost to the Sitefinity fields.  It appears that we are using version `6.2.4910.0 PU` according to the generator tag in the html source of one of the pages.

For example, it seems that there is a boost applied to search values being found in the `Title` to make them rank higher than if the same values are found in `Tag`s or article content, when ordering by Lucene relevance.

Is there any documentation for these boost values to support my findings, or do you have experience with relevance for these?  I'm trying to find a definitive answer to this, and whether or not a customized boost can be applied to the indexing, for example.

This link is the closest thing that I can find to relevance on Sitefinity's website: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/svetla-yankovas-blog/2012/10/25/extending-sitefinity-search-and-searching-by-category

Comment: The best way to find the Sitefinity version is to inspect the source code of one of the front-end page and look for the Generator meta tag. It will show the version of Sitefinity. Please post it here because I have a suspicion that this is not a 3.7 site.

Comment: @VeselinVasilev, thank you for your comment.  Based on the generator tag, the version is  `6.2.4910.0 PU`